# Why we can't overload operator = in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

It is more of a theory question because I am a little bit curious.
For example in C++ you can do things like this with = operator (redone this example from some website)

```
class Counter {
public:
    Counter(int sec) {
        seconds = sec;
    }

    void display() {
        std::cout << seconds << " seconds" << std::endl;
    }

    Counter& operator = (int c2) {
        seconds = c2;
        return *this;
    }

    int seconds;
};

int main() {
    Counter c1(20);
    c1 = 10;
    c1.display();   // 10 seconds
    return 0;
}
```

In Kotlin we can overload operators with "operator fun", but there are no option for '='

What was the reason not to add it?

Comment: For what it's worth, I would consider the C++ code you've shown to be very unidiomatic. `operator=` is typically used in C++ for copy assignment and move assignment operators, and overloading it to be a sort of "construction-by-value-then-assignment" operator with a different type is very confusing. Although mostly harmless in this case (since neither `Counter` nor `int` manages resources explicitly), it would make reasoning about resource acquisition in a larger program very difficult.

Answer (score 3):

C++ has value semantics for variables. So when you declare a variable `x` of type `Foo`, there's an *actual* `Foo` living in `x`. Not a pointer to it, not a reference, not some kind of shared object, but the actual memory for `Foo`. So if I do

```
Foo x = example1();
x = example2();
```

The `Foo` instance that's stored in `x` is the same chunk of memory, and it's that instance that gets to decide how the results of `example2` get assigned to it. That's what `operator=` does.

Now, still in C++, consider

```
Foo* x = example1();
x = example2();
```

This is very different. Now `x` only stores a pointer: a simple numerical-ish value that *points* to the actual `Foo`. Then when I reassign it later, I'm actually getting a pointer to *another*, completely distinct `Foo` somewhere else in memory. In general, it has no relation to the original, and the `Foo` class doesn't get to decide how that pointer gets assigned; it just *does*. C++ decided what it means for pointers to assign to one another, not you and me mortal programmers.

Now, most higher-level languages (basically all of the languages you hear people talk about: Kotlin, Scala, Python, Ruby, Java, Lua, etc.) generally pass objects as pointers. So when you declare a variable of type `Foo` in Kotlin, it's basically a pointer to a `Foo`. And when you reassign that variable, you're reassigning the *pointer*. There's no way to do the equivalent of direct assignment in C++ in a high-level language like Kotlin.